# When bounties are offered for information leading to a conviction, how is it decided who gets it?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, california

Inspired by [this article](https://www.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/news/2021/10/19/auto-break-in-theft-retail-rewards-tourism-sfpd.html), how exactly is it determined who gets the bounty?  Surely the police get many tips, do all informants get paid?  Is the bounty split or do they all get the full amount?  If it is split, how is it decided who gets what proportion?

I am interested in both this specific case and the concept in general.

Comment: I don't have enough info to create a good answer, but generally, bounties are by private individuals and organizations who decide on their own how to award it. Sometimes, it's spelled out. Sometimes, it's just an arbitrary decision.